# Translation of 这庙又不是我家开的

Tags: translation

So I'm reading this manhua to practice my Chinese (I'm A2 level) and this sentence came up: 这庙又不是我家开的

Does this mean “this is shrine is not my home to open”

Answer (score 3):

Tang Ho's answer is correct, but the grammar on the English side is a bit incorrect.
While the literal translation is "This temple actually is not my family operated", the more proper translation would be "This temple isn't actually operated by my family". Phrasing in Chinese is somewhat different from phrasing in English.

Answer (score 2):

> *这庙又不是我家开的*

It is a [topic + comment] sentence

这庙 = 'This' temple' (这庙 is the topic)

The following is the comment:

又 (the actual meaning of 又  is 'also' or 'again' ; when placing before a negative, it serves as a modal word for emphasis, similar to 'actually' in English

不是 = is not

我家 = my family (subject)

开 = opened/ operated

的 = pronoun for 庙

- Topic: 这庙 - This temple
- Comment: 又不是我家开的(庙)- actually is not my family operated (temple)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The phrase `somebody + 家开的` is a very common phrase in Chinese that expresses the idea that `something` is `owned by someone's family` or `operated by someone's family` (this is a bit of a pedantic explanation but it helps with comprehension). One very typical example of this comes out during road rage:

> “路是你家开的啊”

---

This [Popup Chinese](http://popupchinese.com/lessons/intermediate/beijing-autopia-2157) lesson talks about how `sb. + 家开的` works. In their dialogue they even have the example:

> 天是你们家开的？
>   You think the whole sky is yours?

Talking about how people would talk if they had flying cars. You can even have a listen to get a better grasp of usage and meaning of this phrase.

Comment: Oh thank you very much I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

In fact it should be "This temple is not operated by my family."
The biggest problem of Chi-Eng translation is that you cannot directly translate every single word to get the correct sentence. You have to correct the 主謂動賓.

Comment: Thank you a lot!